# How to start a new line in an equation using $$

Tags: equations, align, line-breaking

So I have got a pretty complex equation (with different types of brackets) and it's too long, so I want to break the equation up to start a new line. The equation is:

```
\begin{document}
$$
Cl_f(\vec x):=\min\left\lbrace a\in\{1,\cdots,m\} : p_a Tr(F^{(n)}_a\rho^{(n)}_{\vec{x}})=\max_j\left\lbrace p_j Tr ( F^{(n)}_j\rho^{(n)}_{\vec{x}}), 1\le j\le m \right\rbrace\right\rbrace. \notag
$$
\end{document}
```

How do I start a new line in the equation when using `$$`? Say for eg., I want to break the equation up to start a new line after the colon sign (`:`), just before `p_a`. I would like the output to look something like:

```
Cl_f(\vec x):=\min\left\lbrace a\in\{1,\cdots,m\} :
              p_a Tr(F^{(n)}_a\rho^{(n)}_{\vec{x}})=\max_j\left\lbrace p_j Tr ( F^{(n)}_j\rho^{(n)}_{\vec{x}}), 1\le j\le m \right\rbrace\right\rbrace. \notag
```

I have tried using `\begin{align*}` but it's giving me funny error messages in the log (which I think it's to do with the bracket calls). I am good to use `$$`, `\begin{align*}` or any other method as long as I can get the output that I am after, with minimal packages that I need to load if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `$$` syntax for math environment is used in plain TeX, not in LaTeX, where is used `\[` and `\]` instead.
- For multiline math expression you need to use some of the `amsmath` packages environments: `align`, `gather`, etc.
- Your equations contain errors (unpaired braces)

An working example with your equations can be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
Cl_f(\vec x)
    & := \min\Bigl(a\in\{1,\cdots,m\} : p_a Tr\Bigl(F^{(n)}_a\rho^{(n)}_{\vec{x}}\Bigr) \Bigr)  \\
    &  = \max_j\Bigl(p_j Tr \Bigl( F^{(n)}_j\rho^{(n)}_{\vec{x}}\Bigr)\Bigr),
        \quad 1\le j\le m.
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

**Addendum:**
According to your comments below, I guess that you looking for the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
Cl_f(\vec x) := {}
    & \min\Bigl(a\in\{1,\cdots,m\} : \\
    & \,p_a Tr\Bigl(F^{(n)}_a\rho^{(n)}_{\vec{x}}\Bigr) \Bigr) 
      = \max_j\Bigl(p_j Tr \Bigl( F^{(n)}_j\rho^{(n)}_{\vec{x}}\Bigr)\Bigr),
        \quad 1\le j\le m.
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Zarko, thanks! How do I start a new line after the colon sign (`:`), just before `p_a`?

Comment: @Leockl, on the same way as is started the second equation line. See addendum to answer (will appear ASAP).

Comment: Thanks @Zarko for the updated addendum, but in doing so you have added an extra `=` sign right after the colon sign. I would really like to make the equation look like in the 2nd grayed out box in my original post/question above (ie. on 2 lines only). Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Leockl, your comment wasn't so clear ... hopefully now you have what you after.

Comment: Many thanks @Zarko. Your amended solution worked! I just have one last question if that's cool. Is there an equivalent of `\left\lbrace` and `\right\rbrace` that I could use in `align*`? These two would appear as big curly brackets when used in `equation`

Comment: @Leockl, as you can see from equation code, in it instead `\left\lbrace` and `\right\rbrace` are used `Bigl(` and `\Bigr)`. However, you can use `\left(` and `\right)` if the both are on the same side of equations (between them had not to be ampersand).

Comment: Ok many thanks @Zarko. So under the `align*` environment, there is no way to have **big curly** brackets if there is an ampersand sign in between the two **big curly** brackets, right?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `multline*` environment, as in:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{multline*}
Cl_f(\vec x):=\min\left\lbrace a\in\{1,\cdots,m\} : p_a Tr(F^{(n)}_a\rho^{(n)}_{\vec{x}})=\\=\max_j\left\lbrace p_j Tr ( F^{(n)}_j\rho^{(n)}_{\vec{x}}), 1\le j\le m \right\rbrace\right\rbrace. \notag
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: your first sentence seems to imply that you  can  use `\\ ` in `$$`, which is not the case.

Comment: Hi @José Carlos Santos, do you mean if I use `multline*`, then I would be able to use `\\` to start a new line?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am not totally aware of the differences between `$$...$$` and `\[...\]` and I always use the later. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: Thanks @José Carlos Santos

Comment: `\\ ` doesn't work in `$$` or `\[`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you. I've edited my answer.